# Prove that $x = \sqrt{246}\sqrt[11]{1 + \sqrt{20}}$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:** Prove that $x = \sqrt{246}\sqrt[11]{1 + \sqrt{20}}$ is irrational.

**My Attempt:**

$x^{22} = 246^{11}(1+ \sqrt{20})^2 = 246^{11}(1 + 2\sqrt{20} + 20)$

From here I would typically to apply the Rational Root Theorem, but I can't since the RHS isn't demonstrably an integer. Any hints where I could go next?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, edited.

Comment: It's enough to prove that one of the factors is irrational, correct? I'd try that route.

Comment: @Victor Not quite. $\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt8$ is rational, even though it has irrational factors.

Comment: In your last equation, isolate the term involving $\sqrt{2}$ (don't perform any divisions, by the way) and then square both sides. Keep in mind that for the rational root theorem you only need the factors of the highest degree term and the constant term, so if there's an algebraic mess of intermediate degree terms, you can ignore them. *(moments later)* From two answers that just appeared it seems there's a much easier way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x$ were rational, then $$\frac{\frac{x^{22}}{246^{11}} -21}4=\sqrt5$$ would also be rational. But it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is rational, then so is

$$\left(\frac{x^{22}}{246^{11}}-21\right)\frac14.$$

But this is $\sqrt5$ !